# Minimizing a function in Mathematica

Tags: calculus, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, mathematica

Edit: I simplified the function using $\textbf{Simplify[...]}$

How can I minimize this function of $x$, where $l$ is a positive constant?

$$\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{x}{l}+\frac{l}{x}+4 x^2-2}$$

Mathematica:

> 1/2 Sqrt[-2 + l/x + x/l + 4 x^2]

I tried taking the derivative to find roots, but that didn't work unless I gave a value for $l$. Anyone know how to find an expression (Most likely? Includes $l$). I want to find this function's x-value when it is at its lowest.

Comment: Minimize the stuff inside the radical. If you equate the derivative of the inside with $0$ and multiply through by $x^2$, you will get a cubic polynomials, with roots at the critical points of this function.

Comment: When I put $Solve[D[\frac{x}{l}+\frac{l}{x}+4x^2-2]==0,x]$ I got some weird looking equations. How do I solve for x while not **touching** the constant l?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use Mathematica functions to minimize the function, **Minimize[...]** will do.

In the future, you will probably have greater success with Mathematica questions on the Mathematica Stack Exchange.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that existed! I've tried Minimize, but it doesn't work; or I'm probably doing something wrong.